# how to create trigger in db magento2

Tags: magento2, database, mysql-triggers

Iam running magento2 2.3.5 and i want to make trigger in db between those table which will showing in following :

[image]

this is a table names dropship_order

include 9 column each column will generate from different table such as

- **order_id** will generate from **sales_order.order_id** ,
- **warehouse_id** will generate from **dropship_product_qty_record.warehouse_id**,
- **items_id** will generate from  **dropship_product_qty_record.product_id**,
- **sub_total** will generate from **sales_order.subtotal**,
- **carrier_name** will generate from **sales_order.shipping_description**

so what it the best syntax can i use for this situation ?

Thank you